# How can I handle a throwing closure with trailing closure syntax in Swift?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to do HTTP requests.

```
try Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers)
  .validate()
  .response { response in
    let error = response.error;

   if (error != nil) {
     throw MyError(message: "No good")
   }


   // This line is from Alamofire docs and causes no issue 
   let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: [])

   // do more goodies here which may also throw exceptions
}
```

Since I added the throw, I get the error `Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(DefaultDataResponse) -> Void'`. I had gotten this before, and knew I just had to add `try` in the right place. I thought doing it in front of `Alamofire.request` might do the trick, but it didn't.

I also tried

```
let req = Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers).validate();
try req.response { response in
```

I couldn't find anything about this when I googled for "throw within trailing closures" either.

Comment: Am I missing something here or shouldn’t you change `try!` to `try` to fix the error?

Comment: Updated to say this line was already there - it's from Alamofire docs. Removing the `!` also makes no difference.

Comment: Ok but it’s wrong anyway in my opinion to do `try!` rather than handling a possible error.

Comment: This has nothing to do with trailing closures (as it would be exactly the same issue with a regular closure). It's a design short-coming of Alamofire. The [`response(queue:completionHandler:)`](http://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire/Classes/DataRequest.html#/s:9Alamofire11DataRequestC8response5queue17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_E0C_yAA0B8ResponseVy10Foundation0B0VSgGctF) function takes a `(DataResponse<Data?>) -> Void`, and not a `(DataResponse<Data?>) throws -> Void`. The key here is to "get out" of this closure asap, and do any other computations with the result, separately.

Comment: @Alexander Oh... can you write that as answer and maybe explain a workaround (or maybe there is none) so you can get the points?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The problem comes from the `throw` statement, not the `try!`. Converting the `try!` to `try` would be better practice, but would also cause a compiler error, because it would be trying to rethrow an error from a closure that isn't allowed to throw.

Comment: @DaveStein I don't really have a prescription for a solution. I try to avoid this callback hell wherever possible, usually using Rx.

Comment: @Alexander true but another option could be to catch the error and take some action, must be better than !. Anyway what you say about “get out” ASAP is probably the most relevant here.

Comment: I actually had a failure callback before, but I want to move to exceptions to go use my generic exception handler. I mean even if I use a callback method here, and that method throws, I still have same problem.

Comment: @DaveStein You're essentially discovering the difficulties of call-back based asynchronous code. Unfortunately, this paradigm leads people to invent and reinvent workarounds that are essentially the basis of Rx observables. What you have here is a `map` operation, that in the happy case converts a `DataResponse<Data?>` to a model object, but otherwise throws an error.

Comment: In Rx, this system is modelled as an `Observable<Data>`, which is the Alamofire API which emits `next` events containing `Data` payloads. You're then trying subscribe to that event stream, and mapping the emitted `next` events, into new `next` events which contain your model object. In unhappy cases, your map operation converts the incoming `next` event into an `error` event, which can be handled downstream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments above, I can't throw directly. I ended up doing this:

```
try Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers)
  .validate()
  .response { response in
    do {
      let error = response.error;

      if (error != nil) {
        throw MyError(message: "No good")
      }

      // more logic

      if (anotherCondition == true) {
        throw AnotherError(message: "Error Parsing return data that I expected");
      }

    }
    catch let error {
      uiMessage = "";
      if error is errorThatUserShouldSeeSomething {
        uiMessage = error.localizedDescription;
      }
      ErrorHandler.handle(error: error, uiMessage: uiMessage); 
    }
}
```

I was honestly going to do the `ErrorHandler.handle` call, which is my custom handler anyway. It would have been nice to make it higher up in the stack though.

Comment: "It would have been nice to make it higher up in the stack though." You're not _in_ the stack at the time of the error. Your code is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the closure that you pass in to Alamofire is not allowed to throw. This makes sense if you ask yourself "Who would handle it if this function threw?". Throwing to the scope that you called the function from wouldn't work (aka adding a `try` in front of `Alamofire.request`) because the closure is going to be called after an asynchronous operation and you may have left the scope entirely. If Alamofire had a `do-catch` block around your closure, that would defeat the purpose of allowing you to throw in the first place because Alamofire has no idea how to handle the error that YOU threw and would just have to either eat it (useless) or pass it back to you through a closure or notification of some kind and now we've gone in a circle. In this case, I think the best thing to do to solve your problem is to call out to whatever you would have put inside the `catch` block to handle your would-be `Alamofire.request` throwing an error.

```swift
Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers)
  .validate()
  .response { response in
    let error = response.error;

   if (error != nil) {
     DaveSteinErrorHandler.handleError(MyError(message: "No good"))
   }


   // This line is from Alamofire docs and causes no issue 
   let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: [])

   // do more goodies here
}
```

For future reference, there is terminology and code to define the behaviors the code you've written is exepcting in this case. The `rethrows` keyword means that the function you are calling is going to accept a closure as an argument, and the only errors that the function will throw are errors that come from YOUR throwing closure.

Comment: Just a note that while you do have a handle for `error` from `response.error`, there were further methods I would call with data from response, which would also throw, hence me not needing to only do the special error handler based on that value.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the [`do-try-catch`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html#ID515) syntax.

So, you should do something more like this:

```
do {
    try Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers)
    /* Rest of the try */
} catch {
    /* Runs if the `try` fails
}
```

The error is very misleading.

Comment: I wanted to throw from within the closure, which is not possible.

Comment: @DaveStein Show the whole function definition.